# Java 8 generic collections with optionals

Tags: java, generics, java-8, option-type, bounded-wildcard

I have a relatively simple looking problem that I am trying to solve. There doesn't seem to be an intuitive way to do this or, I am missing something here.

Consider this method to find the main image and if none exists, return first image-

```
public Image findMainImage(Collection<? extends Image> images) {
    if (images == null || images.isEmpty()) return null
    return images.stream()
                 .filter(Image::isMain)
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(images.iterator().next())
}
```

I get an error - `orElse(capture<? extends Image>) in Optional cannot be applied`

Any direction on this would be great.

Comment: This would probably work if it was just a `Collection<Image>`, but the way generics work, `Optional<T>.orElse` can only accept a `T`.

Comment: Can you change the method signature to `public<T extends Image> T findMainImage(Collection<T> images)`

Comment: @misha I get how it works by changing the signature, I am more interested in understanding the reasoning behind this.

Comment: If you use a return value of your collection with a wildcard subtype (`? extends ...`), without binding it to a definitive type (e.g. by assigning it to a variable of the type `Image`, you'll have a `? extends Image` type, where as the `orElse` method expects an `Image` because of type inference. Java generics are a pain, especially when wildcards are involved.

Comment: @sanz The reasoning is **you** know that `? extends Image` which parametrizes the stream is the same `? extends Image` that comes out of `images.iterator().next()` but the compiler doesn't know.  By altering the signature and giving a name to collection parameter you can then prove to the compiler that it's the same type in both places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to fix it is to use a type parameter:

```
public <I extends Image> I findMainImage(Collection<I> images) {
    if (images == null || images.isEmpty()) return null;
    return images.stream()
                 .filter(Image::isMain)
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(images.iterator().next());
}
```

Because then (to the compiler) the `Optional` definitely has the same type argument as `images`.

And we could use that as a [capturing helper](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) if we wanted:

```
public Image findMainImage(Collection<? extends Image> images) {
    return findMainImageHelper( images );
}

private <I extends Image> I findMainImageHelper(Collection<I> images) {
    // ...
}
```

Personally, I would just use the generic version because then you can do e.g.:

```
List<ImageSub> list = ...;
ImageSub main = findMainImage( list );
```

---

Basically...the reasoning for why it doesn't compile originally is to keep you from doing something like this:

```
public Image findMainImage(
    Collection<? extends Image> images1,
    Collection<? extends Image> images2
) {
    return images1.stream()
                  .filter(Image::isMain)
                  .findFirst()
                  .orElse(images2.iterator().next());
}
```

And in the original example the compiler doesn't need to determine the fact that both the `Stream` and the `Iterator` come from the same object. Two separate expressions that reference the same object get captured to two separate types.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(images).stream(). …`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a `List<? extends Number>`. You could not add *any* number to this list, because it could be a `List<Integer>` and the number you are attempting to add could be a `Float`.

For the same reason, the method `orElse(T t)` of `Optional<T>` requires a `T`. Since the `Optional` in question is an `Optional<? extends Image>`, the compiler can't be sure that `images.iterator().next()` is of the right type.

I got this to compile by putting in `.map(t -> (Image) t)`:

```
return images.stream()
             .filter(Image::isMain)
             .findFirst()
             .map(t -> (Image) t)
             .orElse(images.iterator().next());
```

In fact, for some reason I can't understand, it works even without the cast. Just using

```
.map(t -> t)
```

seems to make this work.

Comment: I assume that you really have `.map` before `findFirst`.  The type of `t` is the upper bound of the collection, `Image`, so whether you cast `t` to `Image` or not`, it's an `Image`, and the `Stream` returned is now a `Stream<Image>`, instead of `Stream<? extends Image>`.  The `Optional` is now `Optional<Image>` instead of `Optional<? extends Image>`, and that allows you to pass an `Image` to `orElse`.

Comment: @rgettman `map` can go in either position. `Optional` has a method `map` too, so I have mapped an `Optional<? extends Image>` to an `Optional<Image>`.

Comment: I didn't even realize that `Optional` had a `map` method also.  There's the saying "You learn something new every day", and I just learned something new.

Comment: @rgettman Either way, it's odd that you don't need the cast, no? How does the compiler know the desired type is `Image`?

Comment: Both `Stream`'s and `Map`'s methods take a `Function<? super T, ? extends R>`.  The compiler might be inferring the return type of the `Function` based on the parameter type of the `orElse` method, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: `.map(Image.class::cast)`

Comment: Since the elements are already instances of `Image`, you don’t need a type cast when using `map`, i.e. you can use `.<Image>map(t->t)` or `.map(Function.<Image>identity())`

Comment: @Holger I get that. What I find slightly odd is that you can get away with just `.map(t->t)`.

Comment: Hmm, doesn’t work on my jdk. However, inferring the type argument as written explicitly in my examples, wouldn’t be wrong, so it doesn’t look odd to me. I knew examples, where `.map(t -> t)` can make a desired type transition even without explicit types, before… 
Just recall that when you have a `class A extends B`,
`Function<A,B> f=t->t;` is valid…